# Pivoting rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Below is my raw data:
[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szr9T.png)

I want the data to be pivoted as below : [pivoted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODY5S.png)

```
select cvid, cid,67554,67555,67556,67557 
from #temp2 pivot
    (
    max(lcd)
    for qid in ([67554],[67555],[67556],[67557])
    )as P
```

This is the code I tried. Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility, using fairly generic syntax:

```
select CVID, CID, sum(case when QID = 67554 then LCD else 0 end) as [67554],
                  sum(case when QID = 67555 then LCD else 0 end) as [67555],
                  sum(case when QID = 67556 then LCD else 0 end) as [67556],
                  sum(case when QID = 67557 then LCD else 0 end) as [67557] 
from test1
group by CVID, CID;
```

I tested this in SSMS for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked! It's not still using PIVOT though, But my requirement is achieved.

Comment: That's correct. Both methods work just fine. My method is just a more platform agnostic way of doing a transpose, if admittedly less elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Two things: Make sure you have a source table to pivot.  The source table will include the columns you wish to aggregate.  In this case, I have given it the alias 'src'.  Second, when you are using numbers as column names, make sure to use brackets.  Alternatively, begin the column name with a letter. Example, [67554] as Col_67554.  I provided that example in the code.

```
select cvid, cid,[67554] as Col_67554,[67555],[67556],[67557] 
    from 
    (select cvid, cid, lcd, qid from #temp2) as src
    pivot
    (
    max(lcd) for qid in ([67554],[67555],[67556],[67557])
    ) p
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle SQL, try

```
select * from (
    select cvid, cid, qid, lcd
    from #temp2
) a
pivot
(
    max(lcd)
    for qid in (67554,67555,67556,67557)
) b
order by cvid;
```